# Iterate a function with different input and output types

Tags: haskell

I have two functions that rotate a heterogeneous list to the right/left:

```hs
hRotateRight :: (HInit xs, HLast xs) => HList xs -> HList (HLastR xs ': HInitR xs)
hRotateRight xs = hLast xs `HCons` hInit xs

hRotateLeft :: HSnoc xs x => HList (x ': xs) -> HList (HSnocR xs x)
hRotateLeft (x `HCons` xs) = hSnoc xs x
```

Obviously, both functions have different input and output types (except when the input is a singleton). However, they do have the property that any output of the function can also be an input, that is, the function can be iterated.

I'm looking for a type-safe way to do that in Haskell (I'm not sure if that's even possible). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's possible, with the usual caveat that dependently-typed programming in Haskell it full of holes once you start getting into it.

To iterate a function a number of times, we first need a notion of numbers. The simplest representation is Peano naturals, with an associated singleton type, which provides term-level values that are linked to type-level `Nat`s, a link which you wouldn't get with only term-level `Nat`.

```hs
data Nat = Z | S Nat
data SNat n where
  SZ :: SNat 'Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat ('S n)
```

Define iterated rotation at the type level.

```hs
-- Note: some renaming happened, dropping type classes and reusing the simpler names for type families.

type Rotate1 xs = HLast xs ': HInit xs

type family RotateN n xs where
  RotateN 'Z xs = xs
  RotateN ('S n) xs = RotateN n (Rotate1 xs)
```

Using that, define iterated rotation at the term level, making sure to follow the same "structure" as the type-level definition.

```hs
hRotateN :: SNat n -> HList xs -> HList (RotateN n xs)
hRotateN SZ xs = xs
hRotateN (SS n) xs = hRotateN n (hRotateRight xs)
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/fabbf6636f212577e89d507b5380f54d

See also [Introduction to Singletons](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html), a blog post series by Justin Le.